# set a new password to a user in Meteor

Tags: meteor

here's what i'm trying to do , 
when the user links a social account , the user is then created , but i wish to have the user submit a password , to allow him to log without his email and password .

i created a form to allow the user to submit his password , but i couldn't find the right method to use , the only one available is

```
Accounts.changePassword(currentPassword, newPassword, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            message = 'There was an issue: ' + error.reason;
        } else {
            message = 'You reset your password!'
        }
    });
```

the problem with this method is that i don't know the current password of the user , he doesn't have a password yet but still the user does exist , when i call Meteor.user().

any suggestion ?

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_setpassword :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easy do the follow.

```
  if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Accounts.setPassword("theUserId", "theNewPassword")
  });
}
```

or use `meteor.methods` (untested code)

```
 //server
 Meteor.methods({
      changePAssword:function(userId.newPassword){
        Accounts.setPassword(userId, newPassword)
      }
    })

    //client
    Meteor.call('changePAssword',this.userId,newPasswordVariable,function(err,result){
          if(!err){
           console.log("Congrats you change the password")
          }else{
            console.log("pup there is an error caused by " + err.reason)
          }
        })
```

Comment: Hi @ethaan. In this case isn't the new password transferred in clear text over DDP to the server?

Comment: something more appropiate could be `password: { digest: SHA256( password ), algorithm: 'sha-256'}`

Comment: Thanks @ethaan. I have bit of a basic question in this case. Once this structure {digest:  "", algorithm: "sha-256'} is received at the server, how can it be used by Accounts.setPassword function? Can it be passed directly as the password argument, or how do you retrieve the original password string?

Comment: Meteor is secure by default, if you are using https the string will be secured, so the problem might be no "how you pass it by the wire" instead it could be "how you store on the db" thats where digest came in place